# Will using a smaller mean compared to the actual mean give a bigger variance and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

I'm reading an introductory statistics book and it said this:

"Briefly, when we do not know the population mean, we must use the sample mean as an estimate. But the sample mean will probably differ from the population mean. Whenever we use a number other than the actual mean to calculate the variance, we will end up with a larger variance, and therefore a larger standard deviation, than if we had used the actual mean. This will be true regardless of whether the number we use in our formula is smaller or larger than our actual mean."

I don't get what the book is trying to say when it says that "this will be true regardless of whether the number we use in our formula is smaller or larger than our actual mean". Why would we end up with a larger variance and standard deviation even when we use a smaller number than our actual mean? Wouldn't we have a smaller variance and standard deviation if we used a smaller number than our actual mean?

Comment: When calculating the variance we square the difference between the value and the mean, i.e. $(x-\mu)^2$. Therefore, it doesn't matter whether the number is too small or too large. The difference contributes to the square which gives a higher variance.

Comment: It's because the actual means minimises $\sum(x-a)^2$.